# Netplan did not change my newly set IP address?

Tags: networking

Linux noobie here. So I entered this at /etc/netplan/01-networkd-manager-all.yaml:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp: no
      address: [192.168.0.222/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      access-points:
        "Wifi Name":
          password: "wifi password"
```

Entered these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan -debug apply
```

debug output:

```
** (generate:2606): DEBUG: 11:39:58.743: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml..
** (generate:2606): DEBUG: 11:39:58.744: starting new processing pass
** (generate:2606): DEBUG: 11:39:58.744: wlp3s0: adding wifi AP 'Agujar Wifi'
** (generate:2606): DEBUG: 11:39:58.744: wlp3s0: setting default backend to 2
** (generate:2606): DEBUG: 11:39:58.744: Generating output files..
** (generate:2606): DEBUG: 11:39:58.744: networkd: definition wlp3s0 is not for us (backend 2)
DEBUG:no netplan generated networkd configuration exists
DEBUG:netplan generated NM configuration exists, restarting NM
DEBUG:wlp3s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets: {}
  vlans: {}
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      access-points:
        Agujar Wifi:
          password: *******
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.222/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: enp6s0
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp6s0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for wlp3s0
```

I have restarted my computer but it still uses the dchp ip address.
Weird thing is that when I checked the wifi settings using GUI right at the details tab, it says 192.168.0.24 (DHCP address) but if I change to IPv4 tab, it says it is set to Manual and every thing is the same with what I've entered at the yaml file.
I'm assuming I missed a crucial step here.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctl-Alt T) and enter `ip a`. Post the output .

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2JaLKYM6
I pasted the output here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your yaml file clearly states:

```
renderer: NetworkManager
```

If you are running Network Manager, it is recommended that you make your static IP declaration there:

[image]

I suggest that you revert the yaml file to defaults:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

And follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem! I just wanna make a follow-up question: I see that these two stuffs are in conflict. Why is it recommended to use network manager over netplan file?

Comment: Generally, netplan is for servers where manual configuration is the only option. To use netplan in a desktop installation where NM is running requires some changes that are not trivial. NM works pretty well, so why not simply use it!

Comment: Following on chili's comment, it's also true that even some mobile laptop users don't like Network Manager so you will find quite a bit of netplan advice on configuration through the yaml file.